# Wordpress site not redirecting properly

Tags: htaccess

We have developed a wordpress site recently, if i just type http://example.com in browser i will get the site, but if i type www.example.com it is not displaying anything, what happened to it, is there any problem to my htaccess? My site url and homeurl is http://example.com, i have tried with different options in my htaccess badluck, i just want to redirect the www.example.com to http://example.com.

Comment: You can do that in your web hosting control panel

Comment: that i have did but it is not redirecting, is there any thing i can so in .htaccess file.

Comment: Can you please paste the content of your htaccess file in the question ?

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /example.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Try this into htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check which IP address it points to when www version of your url is accessed ? Is it the same as your non-www version one ? If YES, then paste the below code on top of the htaccess file. Search and replace all the www versioned urls from DB to non-www versioned( if any ).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To check if both urls are pointing to same host, you can use [Flagfox addon](http://flagfox.net/)